# Android getting error: Namespace not specified

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build.gradle

I decided to use latest version of `Gradle` and after updating `AndroidManifest.xml` and `build.gradle` I get this error and I couldn't solve it

Error:

```
Namespace not specified. Please specify a namespace in the module's build.gradle file like so:

android {
    namespace 'com.example.namespace'
}

If the package attribute is specified in the source AndroidManifest.xml, it can be migrated automatically to the namespace value in the build.gradle file using the AGP Upgrade Assistant; please refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/agp-upgrade-assistant for more information.
```

application `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

`gradle.wrapper.properties`:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application
        android:label="xxxxx"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.xxxxx"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.xxxxx"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {}
```

Comment: For some reason Gradle 8.1 was released without being fully supported by the latest version of Java 20... https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#java

Answer (score 23):

To resolve the issue with namespace declarations in dependency projects, I've added the following Gradle script in android/build.gradle:

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate { project ->
        if (project.hasProperty('android')) {
            project.android {
                if (namespace == null) {
                    namespace project.group
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It uses the package name and sets it as the namespace if it isn't already specified in the dependency

Comment: Thanks a lot. This saved me the hassle of editing all the module's build.gradle file by hand.

Answer (score 13):

I have added the following lines to **app/build.gradle**

```
android{
    namespace 'com.example.application
    ....
}
```

be sure to add it to the **build.gradle** file found in the app folder no in the project folder.

Comment: His build gradle is seemingly the one in the app folder, that's what contains the `android` section. I'm in the same shoes. Essentially the Android Studio complains about something missing which is indeed there.

Comment: You don't have to add that BTW, the upgrade script automatically migrates it there from your manifest.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the `namespace` issue occurs because Gradle 8.x is currently supported by Java JDK 17, and not by versions 18 through 20.

The Gradle user guide hints at the incompatibilities:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#java

I'm currently on Java 20, and motifying the *AndroidManifest.xml* and *build.gradle* with the namespace did not fix the issue for me either, but by downgrading to Gradle 7.4.2, I was able to get Flutter and Android Studio to build.

So my advice is to downgrade your version of Gradle, or downgrade your version of Java.

Comment: I have tried everything even wrote the namespace in buid.gradle (app level) but still getting the same error

Comment: @Abhishek - Create a new project from the command-line `flutter create hello_world`, and copy the default settings from that newly created project into your project, or the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

In my Flutter project, I got the same error after the studio upgrade to Giraffe.
Basically from Giraffe onwards gradle only looks at the build file
`namespace` property than the manifest `package` property.

So I have migrated my app-level `build.gradle` file and `manifest`. But it was showing some package was missing the namespace.

So I opened the android folder separately in the studio and tried the AGP upgrade and found out some plugin gradle files were missing the namespace, once I added the namespace property to all of their build files everything worked.

Answer (score -6):

Instead of using a namespace within your `build.gradle` file, use the `applicationId` as shown below,

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myApp.example"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 33
        versionName "0.3.4"
```

If this doesn't work for you, please make a new project setup and attempt to build your app using the new project setup.

```
file >> new project >> project folder path
```

Comment: I think everyone has that. So I have the same string specified twice, once as the applicationId where you say (and that was already there from the beginning) and now the new namespace what the upgrade script migrated from the manifest. The error message still comes.