# Namespace not specified. React native 0.72.3

Tags: android, react-native, namespaces, android-studio-2.2

Namespace not specified. Please specify a namespace in the module's build.gradle file like so: android { namespace 'com.example.namespace' } If the package attribute is specified in the source AndroidManifest.xml, it can be migrated automatically to the namespace value in the build.gradle file using the AGP Upgrade Assistant

Comment: Please add more details: What is the problem you are facing? What do you want to do?

Comment: Check this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76300671/android-getting-error-namespace-not-specified)

Comment: @DinhNguyen i upgraded react native to 0.72.3 and want to run app and this error occurred

Comment: @HarshPatel i already declared namespace in app/build.gradle still it's not resolved

Comment: Can you please show your build.gradle file? Also which  Java JDK version you are using? @PriyaBapodra

Comment: priyabapodra@Priyas-Mac-mini ~ % java -version
java version "17.0.8" 2023-07-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.8+9-LTS-211)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.8+9-LTS-211, mixed mode, sharing)
@HarshPatel

Comment: error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: ./gradlew tasks FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':invertase_react-native-apple-authentication'.
> Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl. > Namespace not specified. Please specify a namespace in the module's build.gradle file like so: android { namespace 'com.example.namespace' }

Comment: So this "invertase_react-native-apple-authentication" causing error. try to add `android { namespace 'com.example.xyz'  ... }` to the build.gradle of this library. @PriyaBapodra